# how to close the inbound Channel adapter after fetching the files from SFTP server using java configuration

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

Hi I am pretty new to spring and trying to fetch the files from sftp server using SFTP inbound channel adapter in java config but unable to close the adapter ,I tried using the below code snippet, But Main isn't recongizing the inbound adapter and so adapter.start() and adapter.stop(); are NOT working . Please provide me any working example of closing the InboundChannelAdapter.

```
public SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
   SftpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(sftpSessionFactory());
   fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
   fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(sftpFolder);
   fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.pdf"));
   return fileSynchronizer;
```

}

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "stream",poller = @Poller(fixedDelay ="5000",maxMessagesPerPoll = "1"),autoStartup="false")
public MessageSource<File> sftpMessageSource() {
   SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(
           sftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
   source.setLocalDirectory(new File("ftp-inbound"));
   source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
   source.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
   return source;
```

}

```
@Bean
@Transformer(inputChannel = "stream", outputChannel = "data")
public org.springframework.integration.transformer.Transformer transformer()  {
   return new StreamTransformer();
```

}

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "stream")
public MessageHandler handler() {

   return new MessageHandler() {

      @Override
         public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
            System.out.println("payload"+ message.getPayload());
            //System.out.println(""+message.);

         }

   };
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "controlBusChannel")
public ExpressionControlBusFactoryBean controlBus() throws Exception {
    ExpressionControlBusFactoryBean controlBus = new ExpressionControlBusFactoryBean();
    return controlBus;
}
```

Comment: You know, I'm closing your question because it isn't clear. You really don't show the code which tries to close something. Although that still unclear how `start()` and `stop()` are correlated with something to close. AFAIK there is no notation in that adapter as *close*. Code you demonstrating is so far so good though...

Comment: Please, close this question as it is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45440330/is-there-a-way-to-stop-the-inbound-channel-adapter-after-files-are-received-from