# Is there a way to stop the inbound channel adapter after files are received from sftp server using java configuration

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

Using Java Configuration how to start/stop the Inbound Channel adapter,I tried using control bus But i wasn't sucessful ,Please provide an example with java configuration .

Comment: Please, provide an example what have you tried so far. The Control Bus and `stop()` invocation is correct way, but we should be sure in code any way.

Answer (score 3):

The `@InboundChannelAdapter` populates `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` bean with the name based on the pattern `[configurationComponentName].[methodName].[decapitalizedAnnotationClassShortName]`. For example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "inputChannel")
    @Bean
    public MessageSource<String> myMessageSource() {
        return () -> new GenericMessage<>("bar");
    }

}
```

will have a bean name as `myConfiguration.myMessageSource.inboundChannelAdapter`.

The `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` is indeed `Lifecycle` and can be managed by the Control Bus:

```
controlBusChannel.send(
      new GenericMessage("@'myConfiguration.myMessageSource.inboundChannelAdapter'.stop()"));
```